# how to make element stick to bottom of sibling?

Tags: html, css

I have created elements that looks like shown below..

[image]

I made the preview above with *flexbox* like so:

**CSS**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper * {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.elem1 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
.elem2 {
  background-color: teal;
  height: 60px;
}
.elem3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 80px;
}
.elem4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 120px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem1">
    elem1
  </div>
  <div class="elem2">
    elem2
  </div>
  <div class="elem4">
    elem4
  </div>
  <div class="elem3">
    elem3
  </div>
</div>
```

is there any way to make the `elem3` element to *float* vertically so that it would stick to the bottom of `elem2`?

please note that I can't use `col-md-xx` because then when in responsive mode those elements' flow will become `elem1 -> elem4 -> elem2 -> elem3` instead of `elem1 -> elem2 -> elem3 ->elem4`..

and also, in my real project the height of the elements are not fixed but depends on the content..

any ideas?

Comment: You need [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Can you post your code..

Comment: and when it comes to mobile view (smaller screen), what is the order? elem 1,2,3,4 OR 1,2,4,3 ?

Comment: How about `display:flex` and `align-items: end`? Please post your code.

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, how can we know what needs to be changed?

Comment: @Gosi with my current code, when it comes to smaller screen, the order becomes 1,2,4,3

Comment: sorry, I thought the preview and explanation was enough.. I've added my code.

Comment: what's the difference with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57345659/8620333 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually the problem is the same.. but since that question have stopped getting answers, I'm posting a new one with what I think is a better explanation and presentation in the hope that there's a different solution from different point of view.. sorry if it's annoying

Comment: you can still edit it and you already received and answer and you didn't react with it ...

Comment: oh I didn't know that an edited question will be pushed to the top of the questions in SO.. I thought it will still be down in the list so that less people will notice it. I'll remember it the next time I ask something here. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping elem2 and 3 together. This way you can set your group position as relative and set elem3 as absolute and move it below elem2.

Try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper * {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5px;
}
.elem1 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
.elem2 {
  background-color: teal;
  height: 60px;
}
.elem3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
.elem4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 120px;
}

.grp-left, .grp-right {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    position: relative;
  }
  
 .elem1, .elem2, .elem3, .elem4 {
   width: 100%;
 }
 
@media(min-width:500px){
  .grp-left, .grp-right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

   <div class="grp-left">
      <div class="elem1">
        elem1
      </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="grp-right">
    <div class="elem2">
      elem2
    </div>
    
    <div class="elem3">
      elem3
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grp-left">
     <div class="elem4">
       elem4
     </div>
  </div> 
  
</div>
```

**Edit 1:**
Added `media query` for screensize 500px.

Comment: thanks! it's getting me closer to what I needed. just a couple things.. why aren't the elements being wrapped (moved to a new line) when in smaller screen? and what if the height of the elements are changeable? (elem2 is a collapsible accordion)

Comment: Glad it helped man, well the reason why it doesn't fall onto a new line when its smaller is because of the width. Its forever 50%, so you need to do media queries to make it 100%.

Comment: I've updated my answer, added media query. Test this screen when it reaches 500px, it will now take up 100% width. So using this, you can add more screen sizes.